# How to get CSS height value (rather than calculated height) in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Assume that the height of an element is set to 'auto'. Trying to get the height in jQuery returns the calculated height. Is there a way to get the actual CSS value (auto) instead of the height in pixels?

```
$('#myDiv').height() // returns calculated height
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/7GrwJ/

Comment: What about `$('#myDiv').css('height')`

Comment: See [Get all css styles associated with an element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/754607/can-jquery-get-all-css-styles-associated-with-an-element), that should solve it.

Comment: Yogu, I don't see how that helps. It returns a potentially massive object, not one style value.

Comment: @isherwood "auto" can be obtained from that object, but it's probably not worth all the trouble.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to retrieve the raw CSS value, see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kWZpD/) for the result (tested in Firefox and Chromium)

I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/754607/can-jquery-get-all-css-styles-associated-with-an-element) to get the raw css object, and [this gist](https://gist.github.com/ydaniv/3033012) to emulate a required function that is only natively available to Webkit.

After that, accessing the property is easy:

```
css($('#myDiv')).height
```

Comment: Of course it's possible, but is this a practical solution? +1 just for making me chuckle.

Comment: What is "practical"??

Comment: Whether it is practical depends completely on the OP's requirements. I admit that at least in Firefox it is not performant because it parses all CSS files. If you use it multiple times, you should implement some caching.